# batch file to open tabs with some time difference in between them

Tags: batch-file

I've written a batch file that opens multiple tabs at once, however, just because of running issues and just because I'm curious to see how it can run faster, I'd like to try out having the files open one by one on their own with maybe a 15 sec difference between them. How can I do this? Using sleep1 maybe?

```
@echo off
start chrome "http://someurl.com/"
start chrome "http://someurl.com/"
etc...
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far.

Comment: `ping -n 5 127.0.0.1` is one common way to introduce a delay: it pings the address given (localhost) at one second intervals the given number of times (so will wait for about 4 seconds in this case).

Comment: thanks TripeHound! Will try :)

Comment: if your not on XP you can use `timeout 15 /nobreak` too

Comment: @SachaDee - Just as I'd got used to using PING to replace CHOICE that stopped existing _after_ XP I learn there's a proper way of doing it!  Thanks.